# I get a NaN error when converting with charCodeAt

Tags: javascript, string, char

How can i fix this issue where the alerted `Encrypted` value is `NaN`?

```
function Encrypt() {
    var Plaintext = document.getElementById("txt").value;    
    var Key = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 1;  
    var Chaesarshifted = caesarShift(Plaintext,Key);//i just didn't paste Chaesarshift code
    var Encrypted;
    alert(Chaesarshifted);
    for (let index = 0; index < Chaesarshifted.length; index++) {
        Chaesarshifted.toLowerCase();
        //till here everything works fine
        Encrypted += Chaesarshifted.charCodeAt(index) - 96;
    }
    alert(Encrypted);// Alert says NaN
}
```

Comment: If you have to add filler text to your question, it means you haven't explained the problem well enough. There's a reason they don't allow you to post a question that's almost all code.

Comment: What is the encrypted value supposed to be instead of `NaN`?

Comment: `Chaesarshifted.toLowerCase();` doesn't do anything. It returns a lowercase copy of `Chaesarshifted`, but you don't store that anywhere. It doesn't modify the string in place (JavaScript strings are immutable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial value of `Encrypted` is not set. So when you are trying to `+=` to it, it doesn't know how to handle that operation.

You should prime `Encrypted` to the empty string `""` for the starting value.

Then, inside the for loop, `Chaesarshifted.toLowerCase();` does not set the value, but must be stored.

Also, your logic is off to append the `Encrypted` text. You need to change the character back into a unicode character. Or possibly even build an array to concatenate later.

Finally, you should start your variable names with a lowercase to follow convention.

To put it all together:

```
function Encrypt() {
    var plaintext = document.getElementById("txt").value;    
    var key = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 1;  
    var chaesarshifted = caesarShift(plaintext,Key); //missing chaesarshift code
    var encrypted = "";
    alert(chaesarshifted);
    chaesarshifted = chaesarshifted.toLowerCase();
    for (let index = 0; index < chaesarshifted.length; index++) {
        //missing code
        encrypted += String.fromCharCode(chaesarshifted.charCodeAt(index) - 96);
    }
    alert(encrypted);// Alert will show garbled text (offset values from chaesarshift str)
}
```

**Edit:** Thanks to [Barmar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103699/i-get-a-nan-error-when-converting-with-charcodeat/52103740?noredirect=1#comment91159704_52103740) to get me thinking about the problem more.

Comment: Are you sure he wants to do addition and not concatenation?

Comment: Thanks for the answer as soon as i get home i'll try it out! (Please correct me if i made any misstakes i try to learn more English)